# How to remove Control bar background outside from Video tag?

Tags: html, css

I made a one video tag and used -webkit- to remove some options.

Just leaved left volume control bar.

And I found there is one background-color outside , how dow I remove this?

I've tried to use 'background-color' , 'color' , 'background-image' attributes to modify , but still in vain.

[image]

```css
  #cmusic::-webkit-media-controls-timeline,
#cmusic::-webkit-media-controls-play-button,
#cmusic::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display,
#cmusic::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display {
  display: none;
  /* background-color: transparent; */
```

```html
<audio id="cmusic" src="http://tw.yisell.com/search_pop.htm?yn=p202900550539464_88012&ym=pa&id=WiHrLDpmwvQ=&yc=21&yt=xPIEJJmxLnS27HbpKOINaq2QBg==" autoplay="true" loop controls='controls' controlsList='nodownload' style="float: left;"></audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

> `-webkit-media-controls-enclosure` maybe this is what you looking for.

```css
#cmusic::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {
 background-color: teal;
}

#cmusic::-webkit-media-controls-play-button {
 background-color: gold;
}

#cmusic::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display {
 background-color: orange;
}
#cmusic::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display  {
 background-color: green;
}
#cmusic::-webkit-media-controls  {
 background-color: blue;
}
#cmusic::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure  {
 background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<audio id="cmusic" src="http://tw.yisell.com/search_pop.htm?yn=p202900550539464_88012&ym=pa&id=WiHrLDpmwvQ=&yc=21&yt=xPIEJJmxLnS27HbpKOINaq2QBg==" autoplay="true" loop controls='controls' controlsList='nodownload' style="float: left;"></audio>
```

Comment: Hi Filipe Prado , yes , that's what I want. Thank you very much!